# accessing cakephp session variable from webroot

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a cakephp application also I have another chat application (non cake) so in order to access the chat application, I placed it under app/webroot. From cake, after login, I am setting the session using this->Session->write method. How can I get this session values from the php script that placed in chat application ?

Comment: Uhm... how and why did you place the chat application in app/webroot? How do you navigate to your webroot now?

Comment: we used to place the non cake projects like forum, chat under webroot. so that we can access it with the url like mycakeapp.com/forum etc. Anything wrong with this ?

Comment: I suggest you to use `cakephp component` or `plugin` for such purpose. like -> http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/wilsonsheldon/2009/01/13/phpbb3-api-bridge

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should put it in the same level as app/ since is not cake, putting in webroot is not recomended :S. Read Rikesh comment and try doing that

still you may access your variables as always... CakePhp IS PHP so every `$this->Session->write();` you use it will be in the $_SESSION superglobal variable.

how do you access it

```
session_name("CAKEPHP");
session_start();
$_SESSION['variable'];
```

The session_name is the name you give to your session if none is given you may skip that instruction. If it is used, use the same name, i think the cakephp default is CAKEPHP.

(can be found out by `debug(session_name());`)

If you don't know the variable part try using var_dump($_SESSION); to see what you have

Usually cake saves the auth data in $_SESSION['Auth']

Hope this helps you :)